# Lubuntu install stuck on "configuring locales..."

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, 32-bit, usb-installation, eeepc

I recently got back my old Eee pc and decided to install Lubuntu on it. All went well, until it got to the point where it configures locales. It has been at that point for more than 1.5 hours now. Even though I've found reports of it taking some time with this, I think there might be something going wrong here.

Any idea what I could do? Any way I could see a more verbose version of the install, just to see if it's still at it?

To be sure: It's a fresh install of Lubuntu 18.04 alternate i386 from USB on an [Eee PC 904HD](https://www.cnet.com/products/asus-eee-pc-904hd-8-9-celeron-m-353-win-xp-home-1-gb-ram-80-gb-hdd-series/).

Comment: In the end, it was the RAM that was not in the slot firmly enough. But still, it would be nice to know if there is a way of checking if it still is doing something or just froze.

Comment: Were you finally able to install it?

Comment: Yes, the install went fine after fixing the ram issue.

Comment: Nice to know that the EEE PC can still be used with Lubuntu 18.04. How is the performance? (I know it would be somewhat slow, but is it usable for reading pdf files, editing with libreoffice, browsing web etc.?)

Comment: I don't really know because I just needed it to flash a bios to another laptop. It did that okay. I tried browsing the web, which was a bit slow. I guess 1gb of ram is just not enough these days.